# Does GitHub have an equivalent of GitLab's CI Lint tool?

Tags: gitlab-ci, github-actions

GitLab has a tool, [CI Lint](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/lint.html), which can be used to validate and check CI/CD syntax for [GitLab Pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/index.html).

Does GitHub have an equivalent tool for [GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions)?

*I have searched but cannot find any equivalent so far...*

Comment: If you work on your workflow directly in the repository, GitHub does help you with the syntax. I think they keep adding such features. However, a linting tool such as CI Lint I also do not know.

Comment: If you work on your workflow directly in the repository, GitHub does help you with the syntax. I think they keep adding such features. However, a linting tool such as CI Lint I also do not know.

Comment: Other than the mentioned helpers in the online editor, there's nothing official, as far as I know, but there's [actionlint](https://github.com/rhysd/actionlint), which you can use locally as a linter. It's also part of GitHub's [super-linter](https://github.com/github/super-linter), if you want to run it was part of your CI/CD itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI as of 28th March 2023 checking syntax for GitHub Actions can now be done via the [GitHub Actions VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=github.vscode-github-actions).

Quoting from the [announcement blog post](https://github.blog/2023-03-28-announcing-the-github-actions-extension-for-vs-code/):

> **Validation and code completion** for the YAML schema and GitHub Actions
> Expressions. Get instant validation and code completion for the
> workflow schema, expression functions, event payloads, and job or step
> outputs.

Answer (score 5):

A bit of this is mentioned as a comment on your initial question, but I personally use the following:

- When building my pipeline I use the yaml extension provided by RedHat
  for VSCode. This uses the JSON Schema store to validate the yaml
  syntax used by GitHub Actions.

  - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-yaml
  - https://www.schemastore.org/json/
- My repositories us the GitHub provided super-linter action available on the marketplace to lint my github actions files. This
  includes a basic yaml linter, but also actionlint (as mentioned in
  the comments above) which would apply to your github workflows. These
  can be ran locally, but I tend to rely on the intellisense within
  VSCode locally, and the linters within GitHub.

  - https://github.com/marketplace/actions/super-linter
  - https://github.com/rhysd/actionlint

Comment: for vscode you can use Trunk (linux/mac/wsl) or Lineter+actionlint extensions to do fully blown linting of the actions. Also there is Github action extension to monitor and debug runs